# can't detect object in large frame

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection

I'm trying to detect an object in a relatively large frame (4000*3000), however, no matter what I try the detector seems to be much more interested in everything but my object. I already tried switching to different detectors and extractors but nothing helps. OpenCV generates a ridiculous number of matches and takes forever to compute.

Here is my detection code:

```cpp
    // get the data
    m_frame_data = m_TeliDevice.getImageData();

    // query info
    auto info = m_TeliDevice.getImageInfo();

    // query payloadsize
    auto payloadSize = m_TeliDevice.getPayloadSize();

    // check if the data was valid
    if (!m_frame_data) return false;

    // check if the payload is valid
    if (3000 * 4000 > payloadSize) return false;

    // initialize the Receive Frame (again) with the provided data
    m_streamFrameBayer = Mat(3000, 4000, CV_8UC1, m_frame_data);

    // convert to rgb
    cvtColor(m_streamFrameBayer, m_frame_rgb, COLOR_BayerGR2RGB);

    // create stream key points
    std::vector<KeyPoint> streamKeyPoints;

    // don't convert to grey for now
    m_frame_greyscale = m_frame_rgb;

    // create, extract and compute the descriptors for this frame
    Mat descriptorFrame;
    m_detector_ptr_->detect(m_frame_greyscale, streamKeyPoints);
    m_compute_ptr_->compute(m_frame_greyscale, streamKeyPoints, descriptorFrame);

    // allocate the Matches
    std::vector<DMatch> matches, good_matches;

    // match the Reference image with the current frame
    m_matcher_ptr_->match(descriptorFrame, m_RefDescriptors, matches);


    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    // Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for (size_t i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {
        double dist = matches[i].distance;
        if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
        if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
    }

    printf("-- Max dist : %f \n", max_dist);
    printf("-- Min dist : %f \n", min_dist);

    // Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )

    for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++)
    {
        if (matches[i].distance < 3 * min_dist)
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
        }
    }

    PIXL_PRINT_DEBUG(pixl::io::info) << "min dist " << min_dist << std::endl;
    PIXL_PRINT_DEBUG(pixl::io::info) << "max dist " << max_dist << std::endl;


    PIXL_PRINT_DEBUG(pixl::io::info) << "good-matches: " << good_matches.size() << std::endl;

    // check if any of the matches are considered good
    if(!good_matches.empty()) {

            // draw the matches
            drawMatches(m_frame_greyscale, streamKeyPoints, m_RefImg, m_refKeyPoints, good_matches, m_img_matches);

            // convert and copy into display frame
            cvtColor(m_img_matches, m_frame_rgba, COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
            PIXL_PRINT_DEBUG(pixl::io::debug) << "Output Matrix Size: "<< m_img_matches.size() << std::endl;
    } else {

        // draw the frame & nothing else
        cvtColor(m_frame_greyscale, m_frame_rgba, COLOR_RGB2RGBA);
    }


    // flip color
    cvtColor(m_frame_rgba, m_frame_rgba, COLOR_BGRA2RGBA);


    // bootstrap the OGL window

    m_img.create(m_frame_rgba.cols, m_frame_rgba.rows, m_frame_rgba.ptr());
    m_texture.loadFromImage(m_img);
    m_sprite.setTexture(m_texture);
    m_sprite.setScale({ 0.2f,0.2f });

    // Extract (almost) native GL Window
    auto& native = m_WindowPointer->get();

    // draw the sprite in the window
    native.draw(m_sprite);

    //Mat H = cv::findHomography(m_refKeyPoints, streamKeyPoints);
    //if (H.empty()) std::cout << "Cannot find Homography" << std::endl;

    // clean up opencv's mess
    good_matches.clear();
    matches.clear();
    m_matcher_ptr_->clear();
    m_detector_ptr_->clear();
    return true;
```

the reference Image gets the detected beforehand like this ( but only once):

```
m_RefImg = imread(str.c_str(), IMREAD_COLOR);
m_detector_ptr_->detect(m_RefImg, m_refKeyPoints);
m_compute_ptr_->compute(m_RefImg, m_refKeyPoints, m_RefDescriptors);
return true;
```

I would like to add some of the Pictures for reference, but they are too big (~35MB) and I don't know how I would add these since the maximum allowed size is 2MB.

Comment: Usually, for object detection, template matching and HOG SVMs are the popular choices. Using some feature detector like ORB may not be the best way to go. Here's a python tutorial on object detection http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/10/histogram-oriented-gradients-object-detection/

Comment: thanks, @ShawnMathew I'm definitely going to read through this!